# How to extract file xml attribute using Python ElementTree -Glue Job

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-glue

for

```
<POR Cli="1" Name="Paul Smith" Street="SN" >
    <Sal Val="1000" Gan="M">
        <Fam dep="1" dog="2" />
    </Sal>
</POR>
<POR Cli="2" Name="Mary Smith" Street="SN" >
    <Sal Val="2000" Gan="S">
        <Fam dep="0" dog="1" />
    </Sal>
</POR>
```

i  wantd extract the labels do xml

```
cli;name;Street;val;gran;dep;dog
```

and after write aws s3

```
cli;name;Street;val;gran;dep;dog
    1;PauloSmith,SN,1000,M,1,2
    2;Mary Smith,SN,2000,S,0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup and the csv module:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv, sys

data = '''\
<POR Cli="1" Name="Paul Smith" Street="SN" >
    <Sal Val="1000" Gan="M">
        <Fam dep="1" dog="2" />
    </Sal>
</POR>
<POR Cli="2" Name="Mary Smith" Street="SN" >
    <Sal Val="2000" Gan="S">
        <Fam dep="0" dog="1" />
    </Sal>
</POR>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
writer = csv.DictWriter(
    sys.stdout,
    fieldnames=['cli', 'name', 'street', 'val', 'gan', 'dep', 'dog'])
writer.writeheader()

for por in soup.find_all('por'):
    d = por.attrs
    d.update(por.sal.attrs)
    d.update(por.sal.fam.attrs)
    writer.writerow(d)
```